# Are Yahoo mail TLDs interchangeable?

Tags: yahoo-mail, account-recovery

I forgot my Gmail password a few weeks ago. During the recovery process, it demands a backup email ID, which is from my Yahoo account. I had registered it as a `yahoo.com` address, but I am not getting any messages on `<something>@yahoo.com`.

Does it matter if it is `yahoo.com` instead of `yahoo.co.in`? Because I am getting other messages on `<something>@yahoo.co.in`.

Answer (score 2):

The two domains do not appear to be linked.

Have you tried as an emergency solution, to register the same username for the .com domain?

You should be able to test the function yourself by sending an email to both addresses @yahoo.co.in and @yahoo.com, and see if both end up in your mailbox. You will also see if you get a delivery failure report. This might also make you able to tell if anyone have registered the same username as you - but on the .com domain.